# Calling Scala Monads from Java #map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an instance of a `scala.collection.immutable.List` and I want to call the `map` method on it, BUT from Java.

I need to supply a `CanBuildFrom`.

I noticed that a lot of the scala collections companion objects contain implicit `CanBuildFrom` instances, but I cannot work out which one I need to use.

Here is my Java code:

```
    Function1<WeatherData, BigDecimal> mapper = new AbstractFunction1<WeatherData, BigDecimal>(){
        @Override
        public BigDecimal apply(WeatherData data) {
            return data.getTemps().reduce(adder).divide(new BigDecimal(data.getTemps().size()));
        }
    };

    scala.collection.immutable.List<WeatherData> data = ...

    data.map(mapper, ???);
```

What should I pass as a CanBuildFrom (the second parameter?)

PS Using Scala 2.10-M5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually get the types right in Java without too much fuss:

```
import scala.collection.Traversable;
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom;
import scala.collection.immutable.List;
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;

public class ScalaMapTest {
  public static List<Integer> parseInts(List<String> xs) {
    final CanBuildFrom<List<?>, Integer, List<Integer>> builder =
      List.<Integer>canBuildFrom();

    return xs.map(
      new AbstractFunction1<String, Integer>() {
        public Integer apply(String s) {
          return Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
      },
      new CanBuildFrom<Traversable<String>, Integer, List<Integer>>() {
        public Builder<Integer, List<Integer>> apply() {
          return builder.apply();
        }

        public Builder<Integer, List<Integer>> apply(Traversable<String> from) {
          return builder.apply(from.toList());
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

It's still ugly as sin, but it works. The problem is that wildcard on the `CanBuildFrom` you get from the `canBuildFrom` method on the `List` object, but fortunately you can create your own `CanBuildFrom` wrapper with the right type.

Comment: I know its ugly and makes the eyes water, but I am coming from the angle of introducing the great features of Scala to a bunch of Java people, and want to show that you could use it as a library, but it makes so much more sense to use it as a language too!  So the fact that its ugly is a bonus :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know what scalac does with the code then ask it. ;)

This is possible with either `scalac -Xprint:typer <file>` or the new Reflection API in 2.10:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> reify{List(1,2,3).map(_+1)}
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[List[Int]] = Expr[List[Int]](immutable.this.List.apply(1, 2, 3).map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))(immutable.this.List.canBuildFrom))
```

Thus, call `map` with this `CanBuildFrom` and all works fine. Does it really? No, it doesn't! The problem is that the Java compiler is to silly to infer the arguments expected by `map`. So what to do? I believe the only way is to create the required values and them cast them to death. Finally mix some `SuppressWarnings-Annotations` in and the code should work fine. ;)

This is what I came up with:

```
import scala.Function1;
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom;
import scala.collection.immutable.List;
import scala.collection.immutable.List$;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;

public class JTest {
  @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<Integer> xxx = (List) List$.MODULE$.apply(Predef.wrapIntArray(new int[] {1,2,3}));
    System.out.println(xxx);

    System.out.println(Test.sum(1, 2));
    final Abc abc = new Abc();
    System.out.println(abc.hello("simon"));

    final List<Integer> xs = (List) Test.xs();
    final Function1<Integer, String> mapper = new AbstractFunction1<Integer, String>() {
      @Override
      public String apply(final Integer i) {
        return String.valueOf(i);
      }
    };
    final CanBuildFrom<List<Integer>, String, List<String>> cbf =
        (CanBuildFrom) List.<Integer>canBuildFrom();
    final List<String> ys = xs.<String, List<String>>map(mapper, cbf);
    System.out.println(ys);
  }
}
```

The list:

```
object Test {
  def xs = List(1,2,3)
}
```

I believe, the best thing is not to use Scala code from Java. It looks ugly. At least, wrap it in some helper classes so that someone who sees this code does not think about an acid attack on his retina.

By the way, sometimes you have to look at the Bytecode to understand how scalac creates values. If you want to create a Scala List is Java you have to decompile the code with `javap -c -s -l -verbose -private <classfile>`:

```
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #20; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   putstatic   #22; //Field MODULE$:LX$;
   8:   aload_0
   9:   getstatic   #27; //Field scala/collection/immutable/List$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/List$;
   12:  getstatic   #32; //Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
   15:  iconst_3
   16:  newarray int
   18:  dup
   19:  iconst_0
   20:  iconst_1
   21:  iastore
   22:  dup
   23:  iconst_1
   24:  iconst_2
   25:  iastore
   26:  dup
   27:  iconst_2
   28:  iconst_3
   29:  iastore
   30:  invokevirtual   #38; //Method scala/LowPriorityImplicits.wrapIntArray:([I)Lscala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray;
   33:  invokevirtual   #42; //Method scala/collection/immutable/List$.apply:(Lscala/collection/Seq;)Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
   36:  new #44; //class X$$anonfun$1
```

Or in more readable Java code:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
final List<Integer> xs = (List) List$.MODULE$.apply(Predef.wrapIntArray(new int[] {1,2,3}));
```

Comment: A couple of things: The `MODULE$` business isn't necessary here, since you don't actually need the `object` as a Java instance, just the static method. Also you'll need to replace `List` with `Traversable` in a couple of places for 2.10.

Comment: @TravisBrown: I tried to compile the code without the `MODULE$` but it didn't work. I used eclipse Java compiler - it has its pitfalls in compiling code which uses Scala libraries. To `Traversable`: Can you show me an example when this is true? I can't believe it because `List <: Traversable`

Comment: In my answer `List.<Integer>canBuildFrom()` compiles and works as epxected. If you look at my edit, you can see the changes that are necessary to make the 2.10 compiler happy. I'll admit that the details of how Scala variance looks from Java are a mystery to me—I just do what the compiler tells me to do, and in this case it wanted `Traversable`.

Comment: True, but there are a load of levels of indirection here already, so what the hell, why not throw on another?

Comment: @TravisBrown: I believe we should end this discussion here and come to the opinion that both solutions are ugly. ;)