# better way to convert from Seq<String> to Seq<Column> in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

When using Spark in Java, we often have to rely on Scala types. In particular, I find that I often need to convert from a Scala Seq of Strings into a Scala Seq of Columns. In Scala, this is easy. I would just do

```
val seq_of_columns = seq_of_strings.map(s => col(s))
```

However, in Java this is much more awkward. I've been relying on converting from Scala to java, doing the mapping, and then converting back to Scala like so:

```
Seq<Column> seqOfColumns = asScalaBuffer(seqAsJavaList(seqOfStrings).stream().map(functions::col).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Yikes. Is there a better way?

Comment: Surely `Seq` has a map function?

Comment: It does, it's just not convenient to call from Java. It requires a CanBuildFrom object passed as the second argument. This is implicit in Scala, but not in Java, and building it from scratch is even uglier than just converting back and forth, in my opinion. I just found this issue which goes into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678756/calling-scala-monads-from-java-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have scala std library as dependency in your project, maybe it's better to work with scala collections inside `.scala` classes and use `java/scala` collection conversion just once - when you have to work with only with `java` or `scala` collection.

One way to map `scala` `Seq` from `java` is using some `scala` object:

Lets create `scala` object `SeqUtils` and define `mapSeq` function:

```scala
object SeqUtils {
  def mapSeq(seq: Seq[String], f: String => Column): Seq[Column] =
    seq.map(f)
}
```

Use this utils object inside `java` class:

```java
Seq<String> strsSeq = CollectionConverters.asScala(Arrays.asList("one", "two").iterator()).toSeq();
Seq<Column> columns = SeqUtils$.MODULE$.mapSeq(strsSeq, Column::new); // you can use `functions::col` here
Iterator<Column> csIt = columns.iterator();
while (csIt.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(csIt.next().x); // will print 
}
```

Another way is use `scala` mutable collections (`ReusableBuilder`)  and `iterator`. Looks not so functional but do the same:

```java
import scala.collection.Iterator;
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq;
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector;
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector$;
import scala.collection.mutable.ReusableBuilder;
import scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

class Column {
    String x;

    public Column(String str) {
        x = str;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> javaList = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
        Seq<String> strsSeq = CollectionConverters.asScala(javaList.iterator()).toSeq();
        Seq<Column> columns = mapSeq(strsSeq, Column::new);
        Iterator<Column> csIt = columns.iterator();
        while (csIt.hasNext())
            System.out.println(csIt.next().x);
        System.out.println("stop");
    }

    public static Seq<Column> mapSeq(Seq<String> seqOfStrings, Function<String, Column> mapper) {
        ReusableBuilder<Column, Vector<Column>> vb = Vector$.MODULE$.newBuilder();
        Iterator<String> stringsIt = seqOfStrings.iterator();
        while (stringsIt.hasNext()) {
            vb.addOne(mapper.apply(stringsIt.next()));
        }
        return vb.result();
    }
}
```